# CakePHP 4 - view helper - error reading session values

Tags: session, cakephp, view, helper

I am still fairly new with CakePHP and leaning with version 4. I can read PHP session values in a template index.php file with below. I think that is wrong way to do but I tested anyway.

```
$userrole_id = $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.userrole_id');
```

And now I am trying to read session values in View Helper so that I can use same code in many different places. But above code throws an error with "Call to a member function getSession() on null". And as you can see in the above one line code, I have Authentication set up and that is working fine. And I have helper loaded in AppView.php, and that is loaded fine, too.

I am pretty sure I am missing basic stuff but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object) does say that what you've tried should work "in controllers, views and cells". But you seem to be trying to use it in a helper? That same page says that in a helper you need `$this->getView()->getRequest()` to get the session object, rather than just `$this->request`. So, `$this->getView()->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.userrole_id');` should work?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the [official documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object), and I needed to do like below:

```
$this->getView()->getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.userrole_id');
```